# Mapfish or Geoserver Printing Module error

Tags: printing, dictionary, geoserver, mapfish

In my personal computer , I'm using Geoserver and print plugin (2.5.2 and 2.4(for print module)).Our development process was completed and We want to use this in our server machine.Java versions, opts and java encoding type are same but When I installed pdf plugin to server machine for example

"serverip:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json"

error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.ho.yaml.exception.YamlException: Error near line 0: Problem getting RİGHT value of enum type class org.mapfish.print.config.layout.HorizontalAlign
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)..
```

what does it mean? 
It is default "config.yaml" file. An error "org.ho.yaml.exception.YamlException: Error near line 0: Problem getting RİGHT value of enum type class org.mapfish.print.config.layout.HorizontalAlign".

I tried very different versions of geoserver and printplugin or mapfish print module same problem come out. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have turkish installed windows. after some problems about geoserver i totally changed my all language, regional and browser settings from turkish to english (us) and got working geoserver interface. but now i'm getting same exception with you got. i realized that some turkish settings is still alive. because i'm getting exception: Problem getting R?GHT value of enum type class org.mapfish.print.config.layout. not RIGHT but R?GHT instead of  RİGHT

Answer (score 1):

The print extension installation should be straightforward. Maybe there is a problem with different versions of Geoserver (2.5.2) and the print extension (you mentioned version 2.4).

I've just installed the latest version of Geoserver and the print extension to make sure it is working, and it works.

I already have Tomcat7 installed on `/opt/tomcat7`. I'm using java version 1.8.0_20.

To install Geoserver:

```
cd /opt/tomcat7/webapps
sudo wget http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.6.x/geoserver-2.6.x-latest-war.zip
sudo unzip geoserver-2.6.x-latest-war.zip geoserver.war
```

The geoserver is automatically installed after the war file extraction.

To install the print module:

```
cd /opt/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib
sudo wget http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.6.x/ext-latest/geoserver-2.6-SNAPSHOT-printing-plugin.zip
sudo unzip geoserver-2.6-SNAPSHOT-printing-plugin.zip
```

After having all /opt/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib, you can restart tomcat:

```
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

Check if the print module was successfully installed:

Go to the **GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR** (`/opt/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data`) and a new folder called `printing` should be present, with `config.yaml` inside.

Check with the following request: `http://yourhost/geoserver/pdf/info.json`

Comment: I'm trying to install Windows Server 2008 OS, I also tried for goserver 2.6 and printing plugin 2.6 and got same errror message." org.ho.yaml.exception.YamlException: Error near line 0: Problem getting RİGHT value of enum type class org.mapfish.print.config.layout.HorizontalAlign"

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue with editing

```
\data_dir\printing\config.yaml
```

file. Just replace all **right** alignments to **rıght**.